# Magento Shopping Cart Rule Condition - Custom condition quote id

Tags: php, magento, magento-rules

I want dynammically create a shopping cart rule to apply to particular quote id.

Any suggestion to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Good Question kim tse.

But the problem is : Quote Id is given random. You must check one by one for customer. How about the customer checkout order less in 1 minutes? We don't know what the quote id and already converted to order id.

But, the answer is **Yes** you can do that. Check this out.

[Shopping Cart Rules with Custom Condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864012/shopping-cart-rules-with-custom-condition)