# Different discount to different customers in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am working on a B2B Magento based project where my client needs a specific functionality. He needs to set different discount to the different customer (suppose that a product is of $100 so he can able to give discount of 5% to the one customer, 12% to the 2nd, 12.5% to the 3rd one and so on...).

How can I achieve the same? Hope you got my point.

Comment: How are you deciding who gets what discount? Just whoever orders first, second, and so on? You could do an event listener that checks each new order to see if it has that product, and if so, changes the price of that product based on whatever algorithm you're using.

Comment: Its B2B project. Client bargain with the customer at his end (may be on phone) and when customer visits our website after login then he will get this discount which they agreed. Hope you got my point!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use group prices. You can create customer groups, assign your customers and you can define different prices for different groups in "Prices" tab of product details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the coupon. The coupon can be applied before checkout and you can automatically create the coupon after the 1st/2nd/3rd/4th/... sales of product.

for reference: 
[Shopping Cart Rules with Custom Condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864012/shopping-cart-rules-with-custom-condition)

Answer (score 0):

You can use promotions at the group level.

Copied from: https://www.siteground.com/kb/set_custom_group_of_users_that_use_a_discount_in_magento/

You can add a new customer's group through the Magento administrative area -> Customers -> Customer Groups -> Add New Customer Group.

You can set the discount for the newly created group through the Magento administrative area -> Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules -> Add New Rule. At the creation page using the Customer Groups fields you can select the customers’ groups for which the promotion will be valid. Enter the other details, set the rule’s actions and conditions. At the end click on the Save Rule button.

Once a customer is registered you can change his/her group through the Magento administrative area -> Customers -> Manage Customers. Click on the Edit link besides the customer and change its group through Account Information -> Customer Group. When you are ready click on the Save Customer button.