# How can update Grand Total on observer in Magento?

Tags: magento, checkout, observers

I have an observer for the event

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savePayment

and I want to change the Grand Total based on some conditions.
I tried with:

> $value = 100;
>
> $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();
>
> $quote->setGrandTotal($value);
>
> $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
>
> $quote->save();

or

> $value = 100;
>
> $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();
>
> $quote->setGrandTotal($value);
>
> $quote->collectTotals();
>
> $quote->save();

But it don't works. Any ideas?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Did you take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363876/how-to-set-custom-grand-total-before-checkout-process-in-magento

Comment: set both grandtotal and basegrandtotal, magento not accept if you set only grandtotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

After the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savePayment` there's another event who update from zero the grand total, so my changes vanish!

Comment: Please give the solution.